# Automatically plan tasks as close as possible to deadline

Tags: ms-project, gantt

I am hoping to use MS project to plan our manufacturing. I have added all of the units we need to manufacture for the coming year, as well as their deadline date (the date the units must be ready to ship). I have also allocated resources and assigned them to each task, and that works nicely (I.E. we can work on exactly 2 tasks at once).

What we manufacture is quite large, and cannot be stored here for long periods so I want to manufacture each unit *as close to the deadline as possible*.

I tried setting the "as late as possible" constraint:

[image]

But when I click the "move -> when resources are available" button, I get an error. I realized it's because the tasks have no dependencies and so could theoretically be scheduled infinitely far in the future. I also realized project doesn't take deadline into account when automatically planning...

So my question is:
How can I get project to automatically plan tasks with no dependencies/predecessors as close to the deadline as possible, while taking into account resource availability?

Or put differently:
How can I get project to automatically plan tasks as if there were both an "as late a possible" and a "finish no later than (deadline)" constraint?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but it would seem the solution is to create the dependencies?  If you aren't tracking dependencies, then project is probably the wrong tool for the job.  You might need to make extensive use of milestones to create saddle constraints (events which must happen between two dates - use the milestones to create artificial limits on the activity).

Comment: @MCW I agree that project might not be the right tool, though I have been searching for a while now and nothing seems to fit the bill... Do you have any suggestions?